# How do I get the trading screen I see on Cryprocurrency videos

Tags: trading, charts

I see you tube videos of people checking crypto prices. It looks like a stockbrokers screen. It must be some kind of software. Does anyone know what it is?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5J5ppaAxTvU

Here is the You Tube video, you can see the software he is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely you can read the URL: The chart in the video appears to be the [Bitcoin/USD chart for Coinbase on Tradingview.com](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=COINBASE:BTCUSD), while theme seems to be set to dark.

Another site used in the video is [coinmarketcap.com](https://coinmarketcap.com).

Comment: I put a link in my comments. It won't let me copy and paste a screenshot into these comments. I went to trading view and that looks like it is what he is using.Thanks for solving this for me.